# Loading images dynamically after packaging in Electron-React-Typescipt-Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

**Description**

I'm creating a replica of the "Jeopardy" game for my college project and chose Electron + React + Webpack in typescript for it. The game is going to need a scenario (made it in .json) to play and the scenario usually involves some images. Obviously, it's better to load the scenarios dynamically so that I don't need to rebuild whole app for every scenario. Therefore I need to load images dynamically as well.

**Actual behaviour**

I made everything work in the dev env so that I put the images in a folder and then load them by name via `require.context`. But after the app is packaged, I find that all of the images were moved to `resources\app\.webpack\renderer\` and their names were changed like that: `f9cbb866db6c9b73d628c76a72d55bc7.jpg`. So, I believe, all of my code was just optimized away so that the images are static now.

**Expected behaviour**

Images after packaging should stay in some folder with old names so that I can change both the images and references in the scenario.

**Code**

This is for loading:

```
function importAll(r: any) {
    let images = {};
    // @ts-ignore
    r.keys().map((item: string, index: any) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
}

// @ts-ignore
const images = importAll(require.context("../assets", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

This is for representing:

```
<img src={images[this._question.imagePath].default}></img>
```

Comment: Putting files you'll read at runtime next to your code might seem tempting but is usually not a good idea. Choose a location on the *target* machine's filesystem (i.e. your user's PCs, for example `/home/[user]/my-jeopardy-game` on Linux, configurable at best) and read all data from there. That way, it won't ever be part of your app's source code and Webpack will have no idea it exists and try to put it inside your app's binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using some official documentation:

First of all, I changed the way the program loads the images: now there is a button to pick a directory and a button to pick the scenario file. After this is done, the program evaluates content of picked directory:

That is how you pick a directory:

```
// @ts-ignore
this.assetsDIR = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
```

This is the evaluation:

```
// @ts-ignore
for await (const entry of this.props.assetsDIR.values()) {
   entry.getFile().then((val: any) => { 
      this._assets.set(val.name, URL.createObjectURL(val));
   });
}
```

Now I have all the images' URLs in the map with their names as the keys. After this is done I can just use the name of the image to get it from the map:

```
<img src={this._assets.get(this._question.imagePath)} />
```

This seemed perfect, but I ran into a problem with the security policy which didn't let me load the image, so I added this line in the `forge.config.ts` file:

```
devContentSecurityPolicy: `default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;`,
```

The line is from the answer to issue on GitHub: https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/2331
and should be placed like that:

```
const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [new MakerSquirrel({}), new MakerZIP({}, ['darwin']), new MakerRpm({}), new MakerDeb({})],
  plugins: [
    new WebpackPlugin({
      devContentSecurityPolicy: `default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;`,
      mainConfig,
      renderer: {
        config: rendererConfig,
        entryPoints: [
          {
            html: './src/index.html',
            js: './src/renderer.ts',
            name: 'main_window',
            preload: {
              js: './src/preload.ts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Also I move assets folder from the workspace folder in User's documents so that the compiler and builder don't see them and don't optimize them.
Thanks to @Alexander Leithner for the help

Answer (score 0):

If the image can sit in any place on your machine, you may want to use a custom protocol to bypass CSP.

According to the answer to this ticket https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23393

You can do something like this:

```
// Give your custom protocol the privilege to bypass CSP
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([{
  scheme: "my-image",
  privileges: {
    bypassCSP: true
  }
}]);

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.handle("my-image", (request: Request) => {
    const path = atob(request.url.replace(/^my-image:\/\//, ""));
    console.log(path);
    return net.fetch(url.pathToFileURL(path).toString());
  });
}
```